# Why are these two proofs of the pythagorean theorem essentially the same?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, determinant

There is a Terry Tao blog [post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/pythagoras-theorem/) from 2007 where he presents two proofs of the pythagorean theorem and presents as "homework" why they are essentially the same.

It hasn't been at all obvious to me why this is the case. The best I've managed to come up with is interpreting the determinant proof as one of the proofs where you "drop the diagonal" (by which I mean drawing a line perpendicular to the hypotenuse that intersects the corner with the right angle). Since the determinant of a matrix is the oriented area of the parallelogram spanned by the column vectors of that matrix and since the determinant is bilinear we can break up the area of the parallelogram corresponding to $\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$ to the areas of the parallelograms corresponding to $\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$. If we place these two parallelograms along the two legs of the right triangle then we have a good picture for the proof of the pythagorean theorem. [Here](http://www.arseweb.com/rupe/pythag/proof.html) is an animated version of the proof. It doesn't directly appeal to determinants, but it has all the right pictures.

This definitely makes the second proof look more related to the first one, but I really wouldn't call them the same because of this. I imagine there must be a better reason.

Comment: You should summarize the proofs from Tao in the body of your question, so that people don't have to visit an external site to know what you're even talking about.

Comment: It appears that the answer is nearly given in the comments on that post by none other than the author.  Perhaps you can refine your question a bit more?

Comment: I guess you mean how he's equating the two proofs in Euclid of the pythagorean theorem? It didn't occur to me the two proofs in euclid were basically the two proofs he gives, but it looks like thats the case. So it sounds like he's saying the two proofs are the same because they both boil down to properties of the determinant. But I have no idea why the similarity proof boils down to properties of the determinant. What does multilinearity, antisymmetry, and rotation invariance have to do with similarity?

Comment: Also, I'm embarrassed to say, I don't know how I would summarize Tao's proofs short of duplicating the arguments. Is this what I should do?